# Как работать с WinAPI

Tags: c#, winapi

Здравствуйте.
Не подскажите как работать с WimApi на C# (в консольном приложении или формах)

Хочется задействовать такую функцию dll, чтобы можно было отследить действия пользователя:
Например попытка открытия какой-то папки, посылка документа на принтер.....

Но дело в том, что не знаю как мне найти нужную DLL, можете есть какой-либо справочник с поиском и объяснением функций?

Можете помочь статями, а лучше ПРИМЕРАМИ(набросать) с объяснением, как это должно выглядеть, тк я не разу не сталкивался с работой WinAPI, те не представляю как это должно выглядеть.

Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Comment: а что вам на это ответил Гугл?

Comment: Много всего, кучу иностранной информации, которую я не могу структурировать и применить к моим потребностям.
Просто прошу с каких бы ссылок начали вы, потому что у меня маленькая паника, не чего не понимаю и не могу найти даже на msdn

Comment: [Шутник][1]


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff818516(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Я это знаю. ну вот допустим.
Необходимо найти dll, в которой есть функционал выполнения чего-либо(todo) при попытке доступа к определенному файлу, как такую найти и найти в ней необходимую функцию?

Comment: @pankovalxndr у вас подход неверный.
При определении задачи вам нужно искать не функции в библиотеках, а практики, которые уже есть и используются. Скорее всего они описаны в блогах или в документациях. Так-что, да поможет вам великий **Goo**gle/**Bi**ng/**Yan**dex поисковик.

Answer (score 5):

Начинать всегда можно с документации: [Использование неуправляемых функций DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/26thfadc(v=vs.90).aspx)
Дальше можно обратится к всяким справочникам типа [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net).
Но применение этих функций, все равно, лучше рассматривать в контекст какой-либо практики. Например почитать здесь: [Взаимодействие](http://www.rsdn.org/?summary/609.xml)
и т.д.